# Perl build using unit test and static analysis

Tags: perl, build

I am totally new in the Perl Build concept. I am working for creating Perl BUILD on Windows 7, and I am successful in running the build for single module. I followed following steps:

1. I used module-starter to create new module. It has lib/newmodule.pm and few testing .t scripts in t directory.
2. Then I ran `perl Build.pl`, `perl Build`, `perl Build test` and then `perl Build dist`. Hence I  get a archived file in the end as an output. I used Module::Build in `Build.pl`.
3. Here the module-starter gives you sample code with test::more module in `t` directory.

So this process I have understood, but I am not completely clear on the build concept. I have few doubts:

My development environment is like this:

- `C:\perl` ---Activestate perl 5.14.2
- `C:\development`   ---main folder for perl code
- `C:\development\project_name\bin\*.pl`   ---PL files (single PL or PL which calls functions from PM files in `lib` directory mentioned below)
- `C:\development\project_name\lib\*.pm`    ---PM files (custom PM having functions being called by PL files mentioned above in `bin` directory)

My questions:

1. Is this directory structure fine?
2. Where should I keep the build scripts in above structure (if above structure is fine)?
3. Will there be a single build script for a complete development folder OR there should be multiple build scripts for each PL/PM file?
4. Is Module::Build sufficient to create the Build for the whole structure including PL and PM files?
5. What should be the structure of Build code? Should it be the same which Module-starter gives you. If yes, then what should be the structure of `t` directory in it? Please guide me explicitly how should be the build directory and which files should be there.

Comment: crosspost at http://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=972189

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time to answer all those questions, but I suggest that you take a little time to simply look at the directory structure of other modules. https://metacpan.org/ has a very nice "browse" feature (when you are looking at a specific module) which will let you investigate the structure of the distribution.

The one question I will directly answer is: you probably shouldn't have to write any `TAP::Harness` code, `Test::More` ought to be sufficient.

Finally one thing that makes your question difficult to understand, and perhaps you don't know this, it that there is a difference between `PL` and `pl` files, so only capitalize these when you mean it; `Build.PL` is probably the only capitalized one that you need.

Comment: Thanks joel-berger and @stevenl ! What I understood till now is that we can keep Development and Distribution environment separate, but still I want to know about the best way of it if I want to use it for my work only (No CPAN upload). I need TAP::Harness to record test results into jenkins where tests will be written with Test::More. I have noticed that I don't have to run "Build Test" batch command, rather "prove -I ./lib -v --harness=TAP::Harness::JUnit" command itself runs the tests and records the output in jenkins.Please give me your views on this.

Comment: looks good, just fyi, the default for `-l` is `./lib` so you can leave it out (just use the `-l` flag)